# What is the right way to load and reload data from server with ng-table?

Tags: angularjs

i load my data in a ng-table from server and have to reload the data after changes location.
This is my code below:

```js
settlementsystem.controller('ContractsController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', '$http', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $http) {

        var contractsData = [];

        $scope.groupby = 'stateId';

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,                           // show first page
            //count: contractsData.length,       // hides pager
            count: 8,         
            sorting: {
                stateId: 'asc'               // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            groupBy: $scope.groupby,
            total: contractsData.length,
            counts: [],                     // hides page sizes
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                                $filter('filter')($scope.contractsData, params.filter()) :
                                $scope.contractsData;

                var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                orderedData;

                if (orderedData != null) {
                    //params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                    $scope.tableParams.total(orderedData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            }
        });

        $scope.$on('reloadContractsData', function (event, args) {
            var request = createRequestObject($scope, $http);
            $http.post('http://dataServer01/DesktopModules/FE21_Services/API/PackingUnitService/LoadPackingUnitObjectListData', request).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.contractsData = data;
                            $scope.tableParams.reload();
                        }
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.contractsData = data || "Request failed";
                        $scope.status = status;
                        alert(data);
                    }
            );
        });

        // set selected row
        $scope.changeSelection = function (user) {
            $scope.contractsData.forEach(function (u) {
                u.$selected = false;
            });
            user.$selected = true;
        }

        $scope.$watch('groupby', function (value) {
            $scope.tableParams.settings().groupBy = value;
            console.log('Scope Value', $scope.groupby);
            console.log('Watch value', this.last);
            console.log('new table', $scope.tableParams);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

        $scope.myData = contractsData;
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            contractsData: 'myData',
            enablePaging: false
        };

    }]);
```

My question for this:

I want hide the datapager. But every time "contractsData.length" or "$scope.contractsData.length" is unknown. I know something is wrong.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove var and add $scope during initialization.



    settlementsystem.controller('ContractsController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', '$http', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $http) {

            $scope.contractsData = [];

            $scope.groupby = 'stateId';

            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,                           // show first page
                //count: contractsData.length,       // hides pager
                count: 8,         
                sorting: {
                    stateId: 'asc'               // initial sorting
                }
            }, {
                groupBy: $scope.groupby,
                total: $scope.contractsData.length,
                counts: [],                     // hides page sizes
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    // use build-in angular filter
                    var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                                    $filter('filter')($scope.contractsData, params.filter()) :
                                    $scope.contractsData;

                    var orderedData = params.sorting ?
                                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                    orderedData;

                    if (orderedData != null) {
                        //params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                        $scope.tableParams.total(orderedData.length);
                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.$on('reloadContractsData', function (event, args) {
                var request = createRequestObject($scope, $http);
                $http.post('http://dataServer01/DesktopModules/FE21_Services/API/PackingUnitService/LoadPackingUnitObjectListData', request).
                        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                $scope.status = status;
                                $scope.contractsData = data;
                                $scope.tableParams.reload();
                            }
                        }).
                        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.contractsData = data || "Request failed";
                            $scope.status = status;
                            alert(data);
                        }
                );
            });

            // set selected row
            $scope.changeSelection = function (user) {
                $scope.contractsData.forEach(function (u) {
                    u.$selected = false;
                });
                user.$selected = true;
            }

            $scope.$watch('groupby', function (value) {
                $scope.tableParams.settings().groupBy = value;
                console.log('Scope Value', $scope.groupby);
                console.log('Watch value', this.last);
                console.log('new table', $scope.tableParams);
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
            });

            $scope.myData = contractsData;
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                contractsData: 'myData',
                enablePaging: false
            };

        }]);

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really the problem.

Comment: But now i have another problem. I can sort the data one time. The first time the sorting does not matter. Please can you show me the error here to? Thx.